# How to implement editor datatable into Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I downloaded editor datatable codeigniter version from this website http://ci.dubbel16.nl/index.php/2015/12/22/codeigniter-with-datatables-and-editor/

But when i am running editor datatable in codeigniter showing error like

> Fatal error: Class 'DataTables\Editor' not found in C:\wamp\www\EditorTest\application\models\StaffModel.php on line *31*

They recommended PHP 5.3.0+ version, And i have using PHP 5.3.10.

Please can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here is my staffModel.php code:-

```
class StaffModel extends CI_Model 
{
    use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Join,
    DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;

private $editorDb = null;

//constructor which loads the CodeIgniter database class (not required)
public function __construct()   {
    $this->load->database();
}    

public function init($editorDb)
{
    $this->editorDb = $editorDb;
}

public function getStaff($post)
{
    // Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
    // Use the Editor database class

    Editor::inst( $this->editorDb, 'datatables_demo' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'first_name' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'last_name' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'position' ),
        Field::inst( 'email' ),
        Field::inst( 'office' ),
        Field::inst( 'extn' ),
        Field::inst( 'age' )
        ->validator( 'Validate::numeric' )
        ->setFormatter( 'Format::ifEmpty', null ),
        Field::inst( 'salary' )
        ->validator( 'Validate::numeric' )
        ->setFormatter( 'Format::ifEmpty', null ),
        Field::inst( 'start_date' )
        ->validator( 'Validate::dateFormat', array(
            "format"  => Format::DATE_ISO_8601,
            "message" => "Please enter a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd"
        ) )
        ->getFormatter( 'Format::date_sql_to_format', Format::DATE_ISO_8601 )
        ->setFormatter( 'Format::date_format_to_sql', Format::DATE_ISO_8601 )
    )
    ->process( $post )
    ->json();    
}

//An additional method just to see if we can still use the Codeigniter database class (not required)
public function getStaffMember($id)
{
    if($id != false) 
    {
        //Use the CodeIgniter database class
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the below changes In libary **EditorLib.php**, the retrieving of the data from our model ‘StaffModel‘ is done with these lines:

```
    //Load the model which will give us our data
    $this->CI->load->model('StaffModel');

    //Pass the database object to the model
    $this->CI->StaffModel->init($db);

    //Let the model produce the data
    $this->CI->StaffModel->getStaff($post);
```

Also try to include the file

// DataTables PHP library

```
include( "../../php/DataTables.php" );
```